# FastRoute Groups in Zend Expressive

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3, mezzio

I want use route groups for FastRoute in Expressive.
Like sample:

```
$router = $app->getContainer()->get(FastRoute\RouteCollector::class);

$router->get('/', App\Action\HomePageAction::class);

$router->addGroup('/pages', function (FastRoute\RouteCollector $router) {
    $router->get('', App\Action\PagesIndexAction::class);
    $router->get('/add', App\Action\PagesAddAction::class);
    $router->get('/edit/{id}', App\Action\PageEditActionFactory::class);
    $router->post('/edit/{id}', App\Action\PageEditActionFactory::class);
    $router->get('/another/{section}[/{subsection}]', PagesAnotherActionFactory::class);  
});
```

I created factories as written in docs (https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-expressive/features/router/fast-route/#advanced-configuration)
And register their in `router.global.php`:

```
// ...
'factories' => [
    FastRoute\RouteCollector::class => App\Container\FastRouteCollectorFactory::class,
    FastRoute\DispatcherFactory::class => App\Container\FastRouteDispatcherFactory::class,
    Zend\Expressive\Router\RouterInterface::class => App\Container\RouterFactory::class,
],
// ...
```

Now I can not figure out where to write the configuration and how to activate it.
Can this be done in the file `config/router.php`?
Help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

you can put them in `config.router.php` as long as the file gets merged with the rest of your config.

```
'dependencies' => [
    //..
    'invokables' => [
        /* ... */
        // Comment out or remove the following line:
        // Zend\Expressive\Router\RouterInterface::class => Zend\Expressive\Router\FastRouteRouter::class,
        /* ... */
    ],
    'factories' => [
        /* ... */
        // Add this line; the specified factory now creates the router instance:
        FastRoute\RouteCollector::class => App\Container\FastRouteCollectorFactory::class,
        FastRoute\DispatcherFactory::class => App\Container\FastRouteDispatcherFactory::class,
        // Zend\Expressive\Router\RouterInterface::class => Zend\Expressive\Router\FastRouteRouterFactory::class, // replaced by following line
        Zend\Expressive\Router\RouterInterface::class => App\Container\RouterFactory::class,
        /* ... */
    ],
],
```

Note the `dependencies` key and that your own `RouterFactory` replaces the `FastRouteRouterFactory` because it shares the same config key.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not supported** and I am not sure if this can be implemented in FastRoute.

You can check the thread "[Zend router - child routes](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive/issues/336)"